# how to remove the ' ' when the dynamic argument is String type?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I want to use jpa `@Query` and found out that the argument of type `String` will be enclosed in single quotes (`''`) in the sql statement automatically. Since it is a subquery, it will cause an SQL error:

```
@Query(value="select cate_id,dt,channel,game_id,new_income_money,new_account,consume from ? " +
        " where cate_id=? and dt between ? and ?" ,nativeQuery = true)
List<TfData> findTfRangeData(String subsql, Integer cate_id, String start_dt, String end_dt);
```

What can I do to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Use subquery inside single quote like construct your query in code itself

Comment: Maybe you should have a look to QueyDSL. Sorry I can't tell you more, I'm not an expert, but a colleague gave me this hint.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature, designed to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks - rather than concatenating raw text that could be exploited by an attacker, it uses a parameterised query to add the parameter in a safe way.

Unfortunately for you, you're actually trying to *use* SQL injection to achieve what you want. You should look at changing that, and instead of building a `String` containing a dynamic query, use some flavour of DSL library.

Spring-Data-JPA supports a few ways to do this, including [Criteria](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html), [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) and [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/).

[This post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) has a quick overview of how to use them.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried two ways to solve my problem.
First,use JDBC.
Second,integrate mybatis framework.Add the dependency to pom.xml and write a mapper to realize my needs.It is quite simple for springboot project.
[image: use JDBC]
[image: dependency and mapper]
[image: the mapper]

Comment: Be very **very** careful about this: `+subsql+`. This is almost definitely the wrong way to do it, and you have almost definitely introduced an SQL vulnerability here (which Spring Data was trying to protect you from). I'd reject this in a code review - there's never a need in modern Java to make a query using string concatenation.